# Issues refreshing UITableView Cell UI Button Images from Delegate Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I am having an issue correctly setting the image for `UIButtons` in a `UITableViewCell`.  I am using a custom Cell in Storyboard with Four buttons to create a Gallery effect and loading the images from a server using an ImageLoader Delegate like in Apple's LazyTableImages' sample code.  I am getting the images back from the ImageLoader just fine, the problem is setting the image.

If I set the images in the `UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I can set the images fine if they are already loaded or just default images:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [posts count] && i < [galleryButtons count]; i++)
    {
        post = [posts objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton *button = [galleryButtons objectAtIndex:i];

        [button setTag:post.userID];

        if (!post.userIcon)
        {

            if (tableView.dragging == NO && tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                loadFlag = YES;
            }
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtDefault.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else
        {
            [button setImage:post.userIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

if (loadFlag)
    {
        [self startIconDownload:posts forIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
```

However when the delegate calls the `ImageDidLoad` method later on, the images are not changing.

```
- (void)postImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forColumn:(int)postColumn
{
ImageLoader *imageLoader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
Post *post;

if (imageLoader != nil)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [timeLineTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (timeLineStyle == 1) //Gallary Style
    {

        int index = (indexPath.row * 4) + postColumn;
        int buttonTag = 200 + postColumn + 1;
        NSLog(@"Button tag is %i", buttonTag);
        post = [currentPosts objectAtIndex:index];
        UIButton *galleryButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:buttonTag];
        [galleryButton setImage:post.userIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIImageView *imageTester = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:300];
        [imageTester setImage:post.userIcon];

        [timeLineTable reloadData];

        [cell setHighlighted:YES];

    } else  // Post Style
    {
        UIImageView *userImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        UILabel *userNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        [userNameLabel setText:@"Image Loaded"];
        post = [currentPosts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [userImageView setImage:post.userIcon];
    }

}
}
```

You can see I have a `UIImage` in the cell for testing.  This is working just fine.  This code also works fine if I remove the for loop in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` up above.  The problem is without that for loop, the button images are not set if the images are already loaded.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with too many pointers preventing the `UIButton` from changing.  That is all I can think of, but I am pretty new with StoryBoard and this style of Custom Cell manipulation.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Up top you set the button tag as `[button setTag:post.userID];` but down the bottom you retrieve the button using the tag: `int buttonTag = 200 + postColumn + 1;` Is that the same?

Comment: That was it!!!  I was setting the user id to later use for a transition.  Thank you so much!  Please submit as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up top you set the button tag as `[button setTag:post.userID];` but down the bottom you retrieve the button using the tag: `int buttonTag = 200 + postColumn + 1;`